# Высота динамического и фиксированного блока без js

Tags: совместимость, html, вёрстка, css

Имеем 2 блока. Один динамической высоты, второй должен иметь высоту, равную видимой области экрана.

Проблема в том, что, указывая высоту 2 блоку в 100%, мы получим скролл, равный высоте первого блока.

Возможно, чтобы второй блок занимал всю доступную высоту, вычитая высоту верхнего? Нужно поддерживать ie8.

Comment: Покажите пример, на jsfiddle или еще где-нибудь.

Comment: @Lucky, https://jsfiddle.net/1udf6z8f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично мой совет. Честно, ненавижу верстку, но когда начал использовать bootstrap3, у меня все вопросы автоматически отвалились после прочтения его документации и использования в production.

А если это нереально применить, то....

Один из блоков должен быть relative, а второй absolute. Точно сейчас не подскажу, но дело все в этом.